# No se me muestran mis objetos por pantalla?

Tags: java, object

Acabo de empezar a crear objetos en java, soy super novata, tengo que realizar un objeto que sea un elemento declarar un atributo con un nombre (supongo que esto es declarar una variable) y hacer que cuando en el main se creen varios elementos se vayan sumando.

Tengo este codigo en mi objeto:

```
public class Element {
    //variables
    static int uno;

    //constructor
    public Element(int uno) {
        Element.uno = uno;
    }

    //getters y setters
    public int getUno() {
        return uno;
    }

    public void setUno(int uno) {
        Element.uno = uno;
    }

    //metodo
    public int contarElementos() {
        return Element.uno++;
    }

    public String mostrarInfo() {
        return "El numero de elementos es: "+contarElementos(); 
    }
```

Mi main es este:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Element primero = new Element(0);
        Element segundo = new Element(3);
        Element tercero = new Element(6);

        primero.mostrarInfo();
        segundo.mostrarInfo();
        tercero.mostrarInfo();
    }
```

No entiendo como llamar a lo que estoy haciendo para que se vea en la consola ya que no sale nada, otra pregunta que tengo es si estoy haciendo bien mi objeto, estoy contando bien mis elementos ?

El resultado entiendo que sería algo así:

```
El numero de elementos es: 0
El numero de elementos es: 3
El numero de elementos es: 9
```

Es decir ir sumando desde el principio mis elementos.

Edito:
Despues de colocar el system.out.print quedando así:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Element primero = new Element(0);
        Element segundo = new Element(3);
        Element tercero = new Element(6);

        System.out.println(primero.mostrarInfo());
        System.out.println(segundo.mostrarInfo());
        System.out.println(tercero.mostrarInfo());
    }
}
```

El resultado por pantalla es el siguiente:

```
El numero de elementos es: 6
El numero de elementos es: 7
El numero de elementos es: 8
```

Creo que no es lo que busca mi ejercicio, dice lo siguiente:
Escribe una clase llamada Element, que disponga de un atributo con el nombre. La clase tiene que contener un metodo llamado contarElementos() que devuelva el numero total de elementos que se han instanciado.

Comment: No entiendo la segunda parte, las dudas sobre las llamadas. Sobre la primera parte, lo que tienes que hacer es decir a tu programa que escriba el resultado en la consola: `System.out.println(primero.mostrarInfo());`, por ejemplo.

Comment: ahora me suma los elementos por pantalla en plan tienes 6 elementos, 7 elementos ,8 elementos... etc. Eliminare la pregunta de la segunda parte y la preguntare en otro tema ya que será mucho lio tenerlo todo junto y lo explicare mejor.

Comment: Edito la pregunta con el resultado actual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

Tienes una clase Elemento con un atributo nombre:

```
public class Elemento {

    private String nombre;

    public Elemento(String n) {
        this.nombre = n;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }
}
```

De este modo puedes crear elementos con un nombre:

```
Elemento [] listaElementos = {new Elemento('Miguel'), new Elemento('Ana')};
```

Pero además quieres saber cuántos elementos se han creado, para lo que necesitas un contador de elementos que sea global a la clase (estático), así que añadimos un contador inicializado en 0 y modificamos el constructor para que sume al contador por cada instancia. Además añadimos un método (estático) para conocer el número cuando queramos:

```
public class Elemento {

    public static int contador = 0;

    public Elemento(String n) {
        this.nombre = n;
        Elemento.contador++;
    }

    // ... resto del código

    public static int obtenerNumElementos() {
        return contador;
    }
}
```

Esto nos dejaría un método principal así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Elemento [] listaElementos = {new Elemento('Miguel'), new Elemento('Ana')};

    for (Elemento e: listaElementos) {
        System.out.println("Hemos creado un elemento llamado" + e.getNombre());
    }

    System.out.println("Número de instancias: " + Elemento.obtenerNumElementos());



}
```

Comment: Wau muchisimas gracias! era mucho más complejo de lo que imaginaba. he aprendido a hacer un array creando un objeto gracias a ti. :)